# Delete openejb web app after installing

Tags: tomcat, openejb

I am using openEjb 3 integrated with Tomcat 6.

Can I delete (I mean undeploy) openejb web app after installing? Or the openejb web app must always exist in Tomcat? Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can undeploy without stopping Tomcat.

1. Start Tomcat
2. go to homepage (`http://localhost:8080`)
3. Login as manager by clicking on Tomcat Manager link under Administration.
4. If you don't have manager settings, add the following entry in conf/tomcat-users.xml:

```
<role rolename="manager"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager"/>
```

Once you login as manager, you should be able to see all apps available in Tomcat. Now you may undeploy openejb app.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to that would be: No, you can't.

Just from trying to do it you can see that your EJBs won't even get deployed.